# Disable Javafx TextField and Buttons after a fixed set of days

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So i have created a Data Entry Application using Javafx and Ms Access, but i wanted to add a feature which i don't know how to implement. I want my application to run for 6 days only and after that all my buttons and textfields will be disabled.

when i click the start button it will *setdisable(false)* all my buttons and textfields and will start the day count and *setdisable(true)* Start button forever. I want to store this info in some hidden .txt file so that when the application closes it will remember the start button status and day count and also display the day no. in a *label*. At the end of 6th day all my buttons and textfields will be disabled forever.

**This is my main class:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class DataEntryMain extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/UI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1280,700);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

**This is my Controller class:**

```
package application;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class DataEntryController {

int rn;

@FXML
private JFXTextField t1, t2, t3, t4 , t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15;

@FXML
private JFXButton start;

@FXML
private JFXButton lock;

@FXML
private JFXButton save;

@FXML
private JFXButton update;

@FXML
private Label resultConsole;

@FXML
private JFXTextField searchRowNo;

@FXML
private TableView<DataEntry> tabView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<DataEntry, Integer> rowNumber;

@FXML
private TableColumn<DataEntry, String> c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15;

@FXML
private void insertData(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    try {
    DataEntryModel.insertData(t1.getText(), t2.getText(), t3.getText(), t4.getText(), t5.getText(), t6.getText(), t7.getText(), t8.getText(), t9.getText(), t10.getText(), t11.getText(), t12.getText(), t13.getText(), t14.getText(), t15.getText());
    resultConsole.setText("Data Added Successfully!");

    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occer In Insertion "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}

@FXML
private void updateData(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    rn = Integer.parseInt(searchRowNo.getText());
    try {
        DataEntryModel.updateData(rn, t1.getText(), t2.getText(), t3.getText(), t4.getText(), t5.getText(), t6.getText(), t7.getText(), t8.getText(), t9.getText(), t10.getText(), t11.getText(), t12.getText(), t13.getText(), t14.getText(), t15.getText());

        resultConsole.setText("Data Updated Successfully!");
    }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception  Occure In Update "+e);
            throw e;
        }

}

@FXML
private void intialize()throws Exception{

    rowNumber.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRNo().asObject());

    c1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText1());
    c2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText2());
    c3.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText3());
    c4.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText4());
    c5.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText5());
    c6.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText6());
    c7.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText7());
    c8.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText8());
    c9.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText9());
    c10.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText10());
    c11.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText11());
    c12.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText12());
    c13.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText13());
    c14.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText14());
    c15.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getText15());

    ObservableList<DataEntry> deList = DataEntryModel.getAllRecords();
    populateTable(deList);
}

private void populateTable(ObservableList<DataEntry> deList) {
    tabView.setItems(deList);

}
```

}

I have 3 other classes which i have used for database operations and i don't think that's relevant here.[This is how the application looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l7NW.png)

Comment: why not simply disable the root parent?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a button "start", which upon click causes everything to be disabled. Then you do a count down for 6 days, which you "disable forever" everything at the end. Why do you need to countdown when you already disabled it on click of "start" button?

Comment: upon clicking start it will enable all textfields and buttons and disable start as to show that the count down has begun and it will end at the end of 6th day

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate Thread use `TimeUnit.DAYS.sleep(days);` in it then run the thing that closes the inputs. You can just disable the entire pane, no need for individual buttons, or make a stack pane with a message on top of everything and show it after x amount of days. You also need to interact with the view from the other thread with `Platform.runLater` and you need to close the thread if the Window gets closed manually with an `onCloseRequest` event on your window.

EDIT:
Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage = new Stage();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        var controller = (MainController) loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            controller.stopThread();
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Main Controller

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextField tfTest;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    private LeKillerThread thread;

    @FXML
    public void btStartClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          //save time to use in Thread? Does not do that now.
    }

    public void initialize() {
        thread = new LeKillerThread(borderPane);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        this.thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Thread

```
public class LeKillerThread extends Thread {

    private Node nodeToKill;

    public LeKillerThread(Node nodeToKill) {
        this.nodeToKill = nodeToKill;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //not gonna test this with days...
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            this.nodeToKill.setDisable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Main.fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="MainController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER">
            <TextField fx:id="tfTest"></TextField>
            <Button text="start" onAction="#btStartClick"></Button>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I did not test this for days... but it works. If you want to keep track of the Time then you got to save the time when you press start and load it next time you launch the program and calculate the difference to right when you start the thread to sleep that amount of time instead of a fixed amount. It may be wise to sleep for lower periods of time in a loop though and not a week. So you have a chance to test if the Window somehow disappeared without telling you (the Thread) about it. It should not usually be a issue thought, only if your Window outright crashes.

Comment: I guess the application won't be running for 6 days in a row so using sleep should be out of question. The hidden text file indicates that the op probably wants to do this kind of check on startup and simply save the time of the first startup. Also instead of doing close requests which could be consumed if you've got some event handler attached doing this in certain situations. Simply calling `Window.hide` should be preferred and is much simpler...

Comment: Yeah, but then you are probably better off using cron jobs or whatever is the Windows equivalent to call the "write something into the file"-task. The op didn't really specify much about why it should do what it does, so who knows if it's running 6 days or not. ```onCloseRequest``` is not a replacement for hide. It executes on calling hide to kill the thread that otherwise would keep running even though the window is gone.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont get that, if possible can you please write the exact code inreference to my code and issue. Thank You

Comment: Did that now. It does not keep track of the time it just waits 10 seconds and then disables everything.